# How to redirect static URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having a php html site hosted on server. I've url like `http://www.test.com/sales.php` when user click on the link of this url then it should show `www.test.com/services/sales.php` instead of `www.test.com/sales.php`.

I've tried following code but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^http://www.test.com/services/sales.php$ http://www.test.com/sales.php [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: can u pls tel me how to do that?

Comment: had tried the other way also but it is not working

Comment: it is redirecting to url but with 404 error the content is not showing

Comment: _“but it is not working”_ - of course it isn’t. A RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that

#### htaccess:

```php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sales/? http://www.test.com/services/sales.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it is adding services multiple times in the url

Comment: updated my code try it its remove folder and extension both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is redirecting but the page content is not showing instead it is showing 404 page

Answer (score 0):

This is the more robust version that can also be used in the real http server configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?sales\.php$ /services/sales.php [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?services/sales\.php$ /sales.php [END]
```

If you want to have a clean URL ("https://example.com/services/sales" instead of "https://example.com/services/sales.php"), then this variant would make sense:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?sales\.php?$ /services/sales [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?sales/?$ /services/sales [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?services/sales/?$ /sales.php [END]
```

It is a good idea to start with a 302-redirection and only change that to a 301 once everything is working as expected. When using a 301 right away you might run into issues with caching, so you should always use a fresh anonymous browser tab when testing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is redirecting but the page content is not showing instead it is showing 404 page

Comment: Maybe I missread what you actually asked. I modified the answer to reflect the different understanding I _now_ have...